# Ionic Frameworks and iBeacons

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ibeacon-android

I'm following this Tutorial https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/09/support-ibeacons-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/ to search for iBeacons in ionic framework, i'm not using a estimote ibeacon, i just using a bluethoot 4 usb stick and make it broadcast with some python script, The android app Beacon Scaner find the beacon, but my ionic app doesn't, i'm new in the ionic world and i don't know how to debug the app to fin the error

this is my angular code in the app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordovaBeacon'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller("BeaconController", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBeacon) {

    $scope.beacons = {};
    $scope.info = []
    $scope.info.push('Controller Init');

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $scope.info.push('Ready to use Native API');

        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didRangeBeaconsInRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
            $scope.info.push('Searching for beacons');
            var uniqueBeaconKey;
            $scope.info.push('Beacons Quantity: '+ pluginResult.beacons.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < pluginResult.beacons.length; i++) {
                uniqueBeaconKey = pluginResult.beacons[i].uuid + ":" + pluginResult.beacons[i].major + ":" + pluginResult.beacons[i].minor;
                $scope.beacons[uniqueBeaconKey] = pluginResult.beacons[i];
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });
        $cordovaBeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion($cordovaBeacon.createBeaconRegion("trendnet", "e20a39f4-73f5-4bc4-a12f-17d1ad07a961"));


    });
});
```

I changed the uuid with the one the beacon scanner app show me (i don't know if this is correct), added some "log to show me in the app", but just show the 'Ready to use Native API' but it seems it never enters to $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didRangeBeaconsInRegion", function(event, pluginResult)

My template code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova-beacon.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Beacons</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="BeaconController">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="informacion in info">
          {{informacion}}
        </div>
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="(key, value) in beacons">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col truncate">
                    {{value.uuid}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    major: {{value.major}}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    minor: {{value.minor}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{value.proximity}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

If some experienced Ionic dev can help i will apreciate it!

Comment: When you test, are you using a device or are you trying to use a simulator?  Also are you using ionic serve or ionic view?